# Is there a way to check simple Django queries line by line?

Tags: django, validation

Working on learning Django, and at the moment (trying to) have a template that creates a list of "robots" that I've created. I'm not looking for help on the specific problem -- I'm trying to figure it out by myself -- but I would like to know if I can figure out **where** I'm failing.

The lookup looks like this. Currently, in the template, it returns nothing (and there are definitely two "robots" in the database:

```
<p>Robotz!</p>
    {% for bot in robots.all %}
    <p>{{bot.name}}&nbsp;//{{bot.serialnumber}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
<p>And that's a list of robots.</p>
```

What I don't know is whether...
- "robots.all" is looking in the wrong place in the second line,
- "for bot in" is bad syntax in the second line,
or
- "bot.name" and "bot.serialnumber" are bad values to print in the third line.

Right now, the template returns nothing: it goes straight from "Robotz!" to "And that's a list of robots." on the served HTML page. Inspect Element in Chrome gives me nothing between those two lines.

Is there a way to find out what I'm doing wrong? Not specific to this instance, but so I can see whether I'm looking in the wrong place, or putting out the wrong output.

Again, I want to figure out how to do this by myself, but I'm looking for tools that can help me know **where** I'm screwing this up: is there something like Inspect Element that would work for Django, so I can see what lines are/aren't seeking and returning data like I can see which CSS lines are and aren't active using Inspect Element?

Comment: What is robots? Queryset? Model instance? How do you pass it to the template? `{% for bot in robots.objects.all %}`

Comment: You can rest assured that you at least have the syntax correct - Django would throw a TemplateSyntaxError if the "for bot in" syntax is wrong. And if bot.name and bot.serialnumber were bad values, you would at least get the paragraph tags and // displayed - therefore the issue must be that `robots.all` is empty or invalid. For that to work, `robots` must be a `QuerySet` instance passed to the template context - check that this is right first. If it's just a list of robot objects, then you don't need the `.all`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) would help you a lot in this case. It shows you all queries that were executed. It doesn't show you queries line by line, but it'll give you general idea what's happening in your application.

Comment: `django-debug-toolbar` is great for giving you everything you need to help - especially with these kind of issues. The best bit here would seem to be where it can show you the contents of the local variables in the template - tell you exactly what `robots` contains.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know `python manage.py shell` that gives you python like shell but more goodies like tab completion or options. It is useful to try different queries/python code in your views.

And as Ondrej Slinták suggested, django debug toolbar is very helpful to tackle variety of problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of syntax. You're likely putting together a list of Robots in your view somewhere, right? I'm going to take a wild guess and assume you're calling it `robots` when you pass it to your template.

In that case, your syntax should be `{% for bot in robots %}`

Have a look at some basic Django tutorials or Django's documentation - they will explain how things like this work in Django.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from main.models import Robot


def robots(request):
    return render(request, 'robots.html', {'robots': Robot.objects.all()}
```

`templates/robots.html`

```
<p>Robotz!</p>
{% for bot in robots %}
    <p>{{ bot.name }}&nbsp;//{{ bot.serialnumber }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<p>And that's a list of robots.</p>
```